# php header printing full html code on browser

Tags: php, json, apache

I am making a simple API from PHP.

Code Snippet:

```
        elseif ($_GET["command"]="verifyconn"){
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            $data=array("response" => "success");
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }
```

Whenever this is executed, I get this response on browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>{"response":"wrong_secret"}
```

The whole HTML code gets printed on browser. When I remove `header("Content-Type: application/json");`, it gets fixed and JSON displays but in text. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you output ANYthing before these if/else statements? `header()` should be used before ANY output.

Comment: No, its a clean PHP file with no HTML code. Not even an echo

Comment: that HTML is obviously coming from somewhere.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't get really fixed when you remove the content type header, but the HTML part will become "invisible", because the content type will fall back to the default `text/html`; if you check the source code of the page, you will see it's still there.

The real solution is to search for where the above HTML is printed and remove it.

Comment: There is no HTML in the whole file, only PHP

Comment: Thank You. Found the solution. The common.php had some part and I just located it. Thank you very much